# Which one is performance wise better Text or extracted TextWidget function?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my flutter code when I am creating an UI lot of places using Text widget. So I converted this Text widget into a function and calling everywhere? Text widget also including some styling. So calling the function or calling the Text widget is better (execution speed)?

Example code:

```
Text('Time left to Entrance exam',style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black
            ),);
```

or

```
Text buildText(String text,double fontSize, Color color) {
    return Text(text,
      style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: fontSize,
              color: color
          ),);
  }
```

Comment: do you understand my answer?

Comment: @JahidulIslam understood, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextWidget` function is more useful than multiple texts. It's absolutely a good practice and if any changes need you can able to change centrally and it's time-saving with clean code. You do not get the execution speed issue. And more important things, in both widget and function you just call a single `Text` widget. That's why there is no performance issue. You go for the second one for good practice.